How will Buddhists refute the following Dvaitadvaita Vedantist Objections on Buddhist view of liberation?
In his Sub-Commentary to the Vedanta Sutra, by the name of Vedanta-Kaustubha to the commentary of Nimbarkcharya, A vaishnava theologian and dvaitadvaita vedantist, Srinivasacharya goes into a particularly lengthy refutation of the Buddhist schools. In the work he makes the following criticism of the buddhist view of liberation. Presenting the objections here, Since I would like to know how Buddhists would respond to their criticism.
The objection is recounted from here.
((Criticism of the Buddhist View of Salvation/Liberation))

For this reason also, the Buddhistic view is inconsistent. Why?
Because there is “fault” in their view of salvation even “in both
ways”. Thus, salvation is held by them to be the cessation of
nescience and the rest. Is this (a cessation) of the series or of the
single members of the series? Not the first, because as the series has
no existence beyond the single members, it (viz. the cessation of the
series) is incapable of (bringing about) salvation. Not the second,
because the single members are momentary.
Moreover, is salvation, consisting in the cessation of nescience and
the rest, due to a cause or not? If the first, i.e. on the view:
Salvation arises from the repeated practice of four-fold truths, viz.
the truth that there is a cause, the truth that there is cessation,
the truth that there is suffering and the truth that there is a path.
2 The truth that there is a cause means the knowledge, i.e.
ascertainment, that everything has an origin. The truth that there is
cessation means that everything is momentary. The truth that there is
suffering means that everything is full of suffering. The truth that
there is a path means that everything is void, everything is
soulless,—on this view, the cessation of attachment and the rest being
admitted to arise from these, the initial proposition, viz. that there
is a causeless destruction, is set aside. If the second, the teaching
of the means will become futile. And thus there is fault in both the
ways.


You should break down refutation of Dhamma into parts and post them as separate questions. Otherwise it is difficult to understand and answer.

There is no efforts by OP to summarize the critique. Readers are required to have a background with or make an effort to familiarize themselves in Hindu philosophy/religion. This is onerous and unreasonable, please rethink this question.

@Desmon Ok, I will break the Question into parts

and post them as seperate questions to make them easier to understand

@SupremeVoid I think this question has been asked before. So it's a duplicate question. Please see if the answers to the linked question answers your question too.
